# How to include multi line script in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, scripting, multiline, elasticsearch-aggregation, subquery

how i have got many examples for making scripts in the elastic search but in the elastic search docs, i didn't find any such thing. Can anyone help. I am using elastic search 7.9.3

Answer (score 0):

you can write multi line script like this in the elastic search 7.9.3

```
 "script":{

               "source":"""
                           .....
                   ...write script here....
                           ......
                            """
    }
```